# What are the requirements to the type of XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange's status parameter

Tags: xmlhttprequest, intel-xdk, sockjs, appframework

Do any standards require that the type of the status parameter in the XMLHttpRequest's readystatechange event is "number"?

SockJs-0.3.4 expects to be able to say

```
if (status === 200) {
```

but when running under Intel XDK's App Framework, the type of the status is "string".

Who is mistaken?

Here is a small test case that shows the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='intelxdk.js'></script>
    <script src='cordova.js'></script> 
    <script src='xhr.js'></script> 
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/appframework.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
        $('#test').click(function () {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", "https://graph.facebook.com/", true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
              switch (xhr.readyState) {
                case 4:
                      var status = xhr.status;
                      alert("Type of status is: "+typeof status+". Status is: "+status+". 'status===400' is "+(status===400)+".");
                  break;
              }
            };
            xhr.send();
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="test" value="test"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What I read here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest - indicates it should be a number.  I'll check it out, but if you have a complete example to illustrate that always helps speed things along.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you're seeing.  Can you provide a complete test case that shows the problem?

Comment: @OldGeeksGuide: I have added a test case that shows the problem (using Intel XDK 0876 on an iPhone 4S running iOS 7.1.2). The problem disappears if I remove the 'xhr.js' include, so that is probably the solution. It would be nice to get it fixed though.

Comment: @OldGeeksGuide: Thank you. Let me know if you would prefer that I report the issue on the XDK forums (or elsewhere). I assume that you work on the XDK team? It seems quite clear to me now that the issue is a bug in the XDK's native XHR implementation. I will probably edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: I seem to be having trouble getting 'onreadystatechange' to fire.  When I try this, it's never triggered.  Is there something I need to do to make that happen?  I could see xhr.status in a success handler, and there it was fine.

Comment: @OldGeeksGuide: timeapi.org seems to be down at the moment. I have updated the example using another URL. You can also test it here: https://services.html5tools-software.intel.com/mobile/aptest.aspx?APP=6bcU5PsUWYkd2mnuCS0ZCty9jSg9GgiM5m4jn_gYJGY&PASS=&PKG=QA&REL=4.0.0&SVR=https://services.html5tools-software.intel.com or download a zipped XDK project here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2B1l-WhDB-ybWFVWDd1TW1EVW8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: OK, I'll give that a try.